# Как в регулярном выражении найти пустую строку?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, mvc

Как с помощью preg_match($pattern, $subject) найти пустую строку. Дело в том что $subject должен быть пустой строкой и не чем либо.Если пустая строка то функция preg_match должна возвратить 1.Какой $pattern прописать?

Comment: Зачем минусить?

Comment: а чем не вариант `$bool = $subject == '';`?

Comment: Дело в том что написано всё с помощью preg_match, Много переделок из за этого.

Comment: Тэг `mvc` как относиться к вопросу?

Comment: Могу убрать, данная функция используется в роутинге. preg_match проверяет REQUEST_URI и если совпадает то дальше выполняется другое действие.

Comment: скорее всего таким образом не удасться проверить строку на пустоту, только `$var == '';` ну или `empty($var)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

так пойдет?

```
preg_match('/^$/', $str)
```

Comment: Не думаю, что [`"\n"` - это пустая строка](https://3v4l.org/r7d4m). `/^$/` - неверный ответ.